# How to get all state code in magento 2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, regions

I am passing the parameters as

`'recipientstate' => $customer['region']` and

```
'cardholderstate' => $customerbilling['region']
```

Right now I am getting the region value's as **ARIZONA** , but I want it as **AZ** in Magento 2.1.7

How to get the solution for this.. I googled a lot but not able to find perfect answer

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: cod you update you code here , it will be easier to help

Comment: I have created an API in success.phtml file, so its very confidential, can't share the code..

Comment: are you getting region data using api ?

Comment: No, I have not used api..

Comment: how are you using code to get region code, ? so i know what part is not working and what is error

Comment: Inside post = ['recipientfirstname'   => $customer['firstname'],
    'recipientlastname' => $customer['lastname'],
    'recipientaddress1' => $customer['street'],
    'recipientcity' => $customer['city'],
    'recipientstate' => $customer['region'],
    'recipientzip' => $customer['postcode'],
    'recipientphone1' => $customer['telephone']];  I am just defining the variables

Comment: but I don't know how to get the region code.

Comment: did you try to use below code ? you need to create / get object of region model and pass country id to it and name of region it will return you array having region code in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Region data by region name defined in `module-directory\Model\Region.php`:

```
/**
 * Load region by name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $countryId
 * @return $this
 */
public function loadByName($name, $countryId)
{
    $this->_getResource()->loadByName($this, $name, $countryId);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: It's not working..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    namespace MODULENAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Helper;

    use \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory;
    use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

    class Data extends AbstractHelper {
           protected $_regionFactory;
           protected $_logger;

           public function __construct(
              RegionFactory $regionFactory,
              LoggerInterface $logger
           ){
              $this->_regionFactory = $regionFactory;
              $this->_logger = $logger;
           }

            /**
             * Gets the region data from state ID.
             * @param $state - numbers state ID
             *
             * @return array [region_id],[country_id],[code],[default_name],[name]
             */

            public function getRegionDataByName($state, $countryId = 'US') {
                try {
                    $region   = $this->_regionFactory->create();
                    $regionData = $region->loadByName($state, $countryId);
                    return $regionData;
                }
                catch(\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

*** Get code ***

```
call helper
<?php
    $helper = $this->dataHelper; //construct it before call
    $helper->getRegionDataByName($address->getRegion())->getCode();
    //see array incomment above to get other data
?>
```